How to pass Refinement filters in PNPJS search in spfx
i am using Sprest from @pnp/sp@1.3.4, i am not sure how to pass the refinement filters I have tried different ways but the results are getting 0, with out passing any refiners its working as expected, but not getting how to pass refinement filters please check my code below
 const results: any = await this._localPnPSetup.search({
            RowLimit: 500,
            StartRow: 0,
            SelectProperties: ["Title","ProductDiscipline","TargetMarket","Audience"],
            RefinementFilters: ["or(ProductDiscipline:or(\"ǂǂ123141243141412412421\",\"ǂǂ421412414124124124\"),TargetMarket:or(\"ǂǂ6163412416667\"))"],
           Refiners:"MMPProductDiscipline(deephits=1000000),MMPTargetMarket(deephits=1000000),MMPAudience(deephits=1000000)",
                  QueryTemplate: Query
        });

